# Display all nodes in a xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Module_Files>
        <Category name="test1">
            <file lang="fr">
                <title>Menu</title>
                <description>Menu list</description>
                <path>menu.pdf</path>
            </file>
        </Category>
        <Category name="test2">
            <file lang="fr">
                <title>Spa</title>
                <description>Services offered in our Spa</description>
                <path>spa.pdf</path>
            </file>
            <file lang="en">
                <title>Gym</title>
                <description>rate</description>
                <path>gym.pdf</path>
            </file>

        </Category>
    </Module_Files>
```

I want to get for each category `<Category>` all files `<file>`. but I only managed to get the first file. I want to display like this (I take test2 Category for the example):

> title : Spa, description : Services offered in our Spa, path: spa.pdf
>
> title : Gym, description : rate, path : gym.pdf

This is my code :

```
 $categoryConfig = $xmlFile->xpath("//Category[@name='" . $categorySelected . "']/config");

 foreach ($categoryConfig as $key => $value) 
 {  
    $rightPanel .= $key . ":" . $value;   
 }
```

And this is what I get with this code:

> 0 : 1:

`var_dump($categoryConfig)` =

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (4) 
        { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "fr" } 
        ["title"]=> string(3) "Spa" ["description"]=> string(35) "Services offered in our Spa" ["path"]=> string(7) "spa.pdf" } 

    [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (4) 
        { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" } 
        ["title"]=> string(14) "Gym" ["description"]=> string(29) "Rate" ["path"]=> string(18) "gym.pdf" } 
    }
```

Comment: You are selecting the `config` child element of a `Category` with a specific `name` attribute. It does not match the XML in your example (no `config` elements). To output each `file` in each `Category` you would need two loops, not one. An outer for the categories and an inner for the files of each category. If you want to output the file independent from the categories you could select and iterate them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops with the `children()`-method will do it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$catname = "test2";
// select all <file> under <category name='test2'>
$files = $xml->xpath("/*/Category[@name='$catname']/file");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    foreach ($file->children() as $key => $value) 
        echo $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

As ThW's comment points out, your `xpath`expression does not match, as there is no `<config>` in the xml. I adjusted it to `<file>` here.

see it working: https://eval.in/102766